# Construct a list for each source records

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv

I here have a csv table containing two columns: "Source_Polygon_ID" and "Neighbor_Polygon_ID". I want to make a list containing a series of "Neighbor_Polygon_ID" as long as the item in the list share common "Source_Polygon_ID".

Here is a sample of the csv table:
[csv table with two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnaGJ.png)

Here is a sample result I would like to get:
[sample of processed result in csv format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVj2U.png)

I have used pandas to read through the csv table and have used groupby function to sort "Neighbor_Polygon_ID" by their common "Source_Polygon_ID". However, this does not help me construct lists of "Neighbor_Polygon_ID" for each "Source_Polygon_ID". Any solutions?

Comment: import pandas as pd
import csv

# Activate Spatial extension in arcpy; set up workspace
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.workspace="G:\\GLUE_Work\\Projects\\NSF\\DaneCountyTest"

# Constrcut a dataframe by reading through the csv file using pandas
df=pd.read_csv("G:\\GLUE_Work\\Projects\\NSF\\DaneCountyTest\\AdjacencyTableDane_cb.csv")

#sourcegrouped = df.groupby('src_GISJOI')['nbr_GISJOI'].list()
sourcegrouped = df.groupby('src_GISJOI').apply(lambda x: x['nbr_GISJOI'])
print sourcegrouped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small snippet that does what you want only using the standard python libraries. I assumed that the neighbour relation is symmetric, so that if A is neighbour of B then also B is neighbour of A (If this is not the case then just remove the second line in the first for loop).

I'm using `defaultdict`, what is a subclass of a normal python dictionary and behaves exactly like it except when you try to access a key that's not in the dictionary. In that case it instantiates the value of this key to be the default value, which you can set when you create the dictionary. In this case it's an empty set. That's why accessing `neighbours[row['source']]` will never throw `KeyError`.

The rest of the code is pretty simple I just read the input file and for each id build a set of neighbouring ids. Afterwards, I write these to the output file.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

neighbours = defaultdict(set)

with open('input.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        neighbours[row['source']].add(row['neighbour'])
        neighbours[row['neighbour']].add(row['source'])

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # Write the header
    writer.writerow(['source', 'neighbours'])

    # Write the data
    for key, values in neighbours.items():
        writer.writerow([key, ','.join(values)])
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That's exact what I want!